shadcn formfield issue with updating an array (react hook form)
Im using cloudinary widget to upload images. I display the images as a preview in my form so i can send it to the database. The problem that occurs is that only 1 image is displayed so my array with images only contains one. Both gets uploaded to cloudinary but the array doesnt get updated but replaced. The field value gets logged twice with the different images.
      <FormField
        control={form.control}
        name="images"
        render={({ field }) => {
          console.log('Field value:', field.value)

          return (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Images</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <ImageUpload
                  value={field.value.map((image) => image.url)}
                  disabled={loading}
                  onChange={(url) => field.onChange([...field.value, { url }])}
                  onRemove={(url) => field.onChange([...field.value.filter((current) => current.url !== url)])}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )
        }}
      />

i tried to use a local state or update before the return.
Here is the code of ImageUpload:

import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Button } from './button'
import { ImagePlus, Trash } from 'lucide-react'
import Image from 'next/image'

import { CldUploadWidget } from 'next-cloudinary'

interface ImageUploadProps {
  disabled?: boolean
  onChange: (value: string) => void
  onRemove: (value: string) => void
  value: string[]
}

function ImageUpload({ disabled, onChange, onRemove, value }: ImageUploadProps) {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true)
  }, [])

  const onUpload = useCallback(
    (result: any) => {
      onChange(result.info.secure_url)
    },
    [onChange]
  )

  if (!isMounted) return null

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="mb-4 flex items-center gap-4">
        {value.map((url) => (
          <div key={url} className="relative h-[200px] w-[200px] overflow-hidden rounded-md">
            <div className="absolute right-2 top-2 z-10">
              <Button type="button" onClick={() => onRemove(url)} variant="destructive" size="icon">
                <Trash className="h-4 w-4" />
              </Button>
            </div>
            <Image fill className="object-cover" alt="image" src={url} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <CldUploadWidget onSuccess={onUpload} uploadPreset="erx1yvtk">
        {({ open }) => {
          const onClick = () => {
            open()
          }
          return (
            <Button type="button" disabled={disabled} variant="secondary" onClick={onClick}>
              <ImagePlus className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
              Upload an Image
            </Button>
          )
        }}
      </CldUploadWidget>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImageUpload```



Here is a solution i came up with. this is a part of the form, only images upload gives an error now, that an array is expected instead of a function. If get the function out of the onChange it does not work. 

'use client'

import { AlertModal } from '@/components/modals/alert-modal'
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import { Checkbox } from '@/components/ui/checkbox'
import { Form, FormControl, FormDescription, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage } from '@/components/ui/form'
import Heading from '@/components/ui/heading'
import ImageUpload from '@/components/ui/imageUpload'
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input'
import { Select, SelectContent, SelectItem, SelectTrigger, SelectValue } from '@/components/ui/select'
import { Separator } from '@/components/ui/separator'
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { Category, Image, Product } from '@prisma/client'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Trash } from 'lucide-react'
import { useParams, useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import * as z from 'zod'

interface ProductFormProps {
  initialData:
    | (Product & {
        images: Image[]
      })
    | null
  categories: Category[]
}

const formSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1),
  images: z.object({ url: z.string() }).array(),
  price: z.coerce.number().min(1),
  categoryId: z.string().min(1),
  isFeatured: z.boolean().default(false).optional(),
  isArchived: z.boolean().default(false).optional()
})

type ProductFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>

function ProductForm({ initialData, categories }: ProductFormProps) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const { toast } = useToast()
  const router = useRouter()
  const params = useParams()

  const title = initialData ? 'Edit Product' : 'New Product'
  const description = initialData ? 'Update your product settings here' : 'Create a new product'
  const toastMessage = initialData ? 'Your product has been updated.' : 'Your product has been created.'
  const action = initialData ? 'Save changes' : 'Create product'

  const form = useForm<ProductFormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: initialData
      ? {
          ...initialData,
          price: parseFloat(String(initialData?.price))
        }
      : {
          name: '',
          images: [],
          price: 0,
          categoryId: '',
          isFeatured: false,
          isArchived: false
        }
  })

  const onSubmit = async (data: ProductFormValues) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      if (initialData) {
        await axios.patch(`/api/${params.storeId}/products/${params.productId}`, data)
      } else {
        await axios.post(`/api/${params.storeId}/products`, data)
      }
      router.refresh()
      router.push(`/${params.storeId}/products`)
      toast({
        title: 'Success!',
        description: toastMessage
      })
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: 'Uh oh! Something went wrong.',
        description: 'There was a problem with your request.'
      })
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  const onDelete = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      await axios.delete(`/api/${params.storeId}/products/${params.productId}`)
      router.refresh()
      router.push(`/${params.storeId}/products`)
      toast({
        title: 'Success!',
        description: 'Your product has been deleted.'
      })
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: 'Uh oh! Something went wrong.',
        description: 'There was a problem with your request.'
      })
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
      setOpen(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AlertModal isOpen={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} onConfirm={onDelete} loading={loading} />
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <Heading title={title} description={description} />
        {initialData && (
          <Button disabled={loading} variant="destructive" size="icon" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
            <Trash className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
      <Separator />
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-full space-y-8">
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="images"
            render={({ field }) => {
              console.log('array', field.value)
              // Handle image addition
              const handleImageChange = (url: string) => {
                // Update the form state with the new images array
                field.onChange((prev: Image[]) => [...(prev || []), { url }])
              }

              // Handle image removal
              const handleImageRemove = (url: string) => {
                // Update the form state with the filtered images array
                field.onChange((prev: Image[]) => (prev || []).filter((image) => image.url !== url) as Image[])
              }

              return (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Images</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <ImageUpload
                      value={field.value.map((image) => image.url)} // Pass only the image URLs to the ImageUpload component
                      disabled={loading}
                      onChange={handleImageChange} // Call handleImageChange on image addition
                      onRemove={handleImageRemove} // Call handleImageRemove on image removal
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )
            }}
          />


Can you update your question to include the code for your ImageUpload component?

Hey i updated the code with the imageUpload.
Also i tried to fix that more images render that i upload but now if try to submit it says expected an Array instead of a function.  i will also upload the full code of that

@AlessioTortora hey, am having the same issue, did you find any solution?

@PranavAnand
this was the solution:
adding this weird syntax works.
onChange={(url) => { field.onChange(
(field.value = [...field.value, { url }])
);}}

@AlessioTortora Hey I have replied to one of the other question you posted regarding the same issue. Check that out, that solved my issue

@PranavAnand the onChange what i wrote also solved it. But thanks for reminding me :)
